# Merge first n bits of a byte with last 8-n bits of another byte

Tags: c#, java

How can I merge first n bits of a byte with last 8-n bits of another byte?

I know something like below for picking 3 bits from first and 5 from second (Which I have observed in DES encryption algorithm) 

`zByte=(xByte & 0xE0) | (yByte & 0x1F);` 
But I don't know maths behind why we need to use 0XE0 and 0X1F in this case. So I am trying to understand the details with regards to each bit.

Comment: `C#` or `Java`? Pick one. Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: merge means concatenation, AND?OR?

Comment: I know both Java & C#, doesn't matter in which language I would receive answer. I can interpret it in other language.

I know something like below for picking 3 bits from first and 5 from second (Which I have observed in DES encryption algorithm)

zByte=(xByte & 0xE0) | (yByte & 0x1F);




But I don't know maths behind why we need to use E0 and 1F in this case.  So I am trying to understand the details with regards to each bit.

@RajeshSubramanian I mean concatenation.

Comment: This isn't concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The math behind those numbers (0xE0 and 0x1F) is quite simple. First we are exploiting the fact that `0 & <bit>` always equals `0` and `1 & <bit>` always equals `<bit>`.

0x1F is 00011111 binary, which means that the first 3 bits will always be 0 after an & operation with another byte - and the last 5 bits will be the same they were in the other byte. Remember that every 1 in a binary number represents a power of 2, so if you want to find the mask mathematically it would be the sum of 2^x from x = 0 to n-1.  Then you can find the opposite mask (the one that is 11100000) to extract the first 3 bit, you simply need to subtract the mask from 11111111, and you will get 11100000 (0xE0).

Answer (score 5):

In C#, that would be something like:

```
    int mask = ~((-1) << n);
    var result = (x & ~mask) | (y & mask);
```

i.e. we build a mask that is (for n = 5) : `000....0011111`, then we combine (`&`) one operand with that mask, the other operand with the *inverse* (`~`) of the mask, and compose them (`|`).

You could also probably do something more quickly just using shift operations (avoiding a mask completely) - but only if the data can be treated as `unsigned` (so Java might struggle here).

Comment: you can make the mask like this: `int mask = 0xff >> n;`

Comment: @LorentzVedeler given that the example is n = 17, that won't work. Also, for a full-width operation, it would need to be unsigned - problematic on Java. But: an option presents itself which should work fine. Will update... better?

Comment: Yes that's nice. btw, Java has an unsigned right shift, so you could also do `-1 >>> -n` (slightly more verbose in C#), with slightly different properties ("mirrored" properties, in a sense).

Answer (score 2):

It just sounds like you don't understand how boolean arithmetic works? If this is your question it works like this:

`0xEO` and `0x1F` are hexidecimal representations of numbers. If we convert these numbers to binary they would be:

```
0xE0 = 11100000
0x1F = 00011111
```

Additionally & (and) and | (or) are bitwise logical operators. To understand logical operators, first remember the 1 = true and 0 = false.

The truth table for & is:

```
0 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

The truth table for | is:

```
0 | 0 = 0
0 | 1 = 1
1 | 0 = 1
1 | 1 = 1
```

So let's breakdown your equation piece by piece. First we will evaluate the code in parenthesis first. We will walk through each number in binary and for the & operator if each operand has a 1 in the same bit position we will return 1. If either number has a 0 then we will return 0. After we finish the evaluation of the operands in the parenthesis we will then take the 2 resulting numbers and apply the | operator bit by bit. If either number has a 1 in the same bit position we will return 1. If both numbers have a 0 in the same bit position we will return 0.

For the sake of discussion, let's say that

```
xByte = 255 or (FF in hex and 11111111 in binary)
yByte = 0 or (00 in hex and 00000000 in binary)
```

When you apply the & and | operators we are going to compare each bit one at a time:

```
zByte = (xByte & 0xEO) | (yByte & 0x1F)
```

becomes:

```
zByte = (11111111 & 11100000) | (00000000 & 00011111)
zByte = 111000000 | 00000000
zByte = 11100000
```

If you understand this and how boolean logic works then you can use [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)'s answer.

Comment: Hello Brother...

I know truth table and I know what is HEX, Binary and any other format for that matter. I think you didn't understand my question.

Can you tell me how you will extract first 2 bits or last 2 bits from a byte? Then I will manage from there on...

Comment: @SudhakarChavali to extract bits, you typically "and" with a mask, exactly like everyone keeps saying...

Answer (score 0):

In java,

By using the following function we can get the first n bits of the first Byte and last 8 n bits of the second byte.

public class BitExample {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Byte a = 15;
    Byte b = 16;
    String mergedValue=merge(4, a, b);
    System.out.println(mergedValue);
}


public static String merge(int n, Byte a, Byte b) {
    String mergedString = "";
    String sa = Integer.toBinaryString(a);
    String sb = Integer.toBinaryString(b);

    if(n>sa.length()) {
        for(int i=0; i<(n-sa.length()); i++) {
            mergedString+="0";
        }
        mergedString+=sa;
    }else{
        mergedString+=sa.substring(0, n);
    }

    if(8*n>sb.length()) {
        for(int i=0; i<(8*n-sb.length()); i++) {
            mergedString+="0";
        }
        mergedString+=sb;
    }
    return mergedString;
}
```

}

Comment: That is quite possibly the most unnecessarily convoluted way of performing bit ops that I've ever seen. Computers are **designed** to work with bits - doing everything as a string is essentially also known as "doing it wrong".

Comment: Ok,
thanks for your valuable reply, we'll try to improve my skill in bit manipulation.